# Photo and data sorting software

Tags: software, metadata, photo-management, file-management

I would like to be able to have thumbnail images of my photographs with information next to them (Location, Photo ID #, Date Photo Taken, etc.) that I can sort according to the column headers (like in Excel).  I tried creating a Pivot Table in Excel, but it didn't work (may not have done it correctly).  Is there any software available that is already set up to do this?

Comment: Not sure why you are trying to do this in excel. Those are items in the exif and can be sorted with picasa.

Comment: Are you looking to create database for your self to keep track of images or do you just need piece of software that will manage your photos (sorting by date, name, focal length, keywords and etc)? I'm little confused like @AndyML as to why are you using Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the list of the photo management software programs that can help you (sorted alphabetically):

- [Adobe Bridge](http://adobe.com)
- [Adobe Photoshop Lightroom](http://adobe.com)
- [Adobe Photoshop Elements](http://adobe.com)
- [ACDSee](http://acdsee.com)
- [Daminion](http://daminion.net) (this is our product)
- [Picasa](http://google.com/picasa)
- [PicaJet](http://picajet.com)
- [MediaPro](http://phaseone.com) (former iView or ExpressionMedia)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Mac this can easily be achieved in Aperture, I dont think you can do this in Lightroom.

[image]

I think this is what you ment, if you don't have a Mac, you can do this with ACDSee on Windows, maybe Picasa but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Bridge is very handy tool for photos management, you can load all the images you have in it and sort them by name, date created, size, type and more. If you have Photoshop then Bridge is installed already on your system as it's part of the Photoshop package.

Comment: At least I can't make sense of that last sentence. Would you care to rephrase it?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling sorry for that, that was a byproduct of thinking and typing at the same time :)